# React: added script tag to head but still not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use `react-places-autocomplete` in my react project. It asks to use `Google Maps JavaScript API`. I included it using the following code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const googleMapsScriptEl = document.createElement('script');
    googleMapsScriptEl.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&libraries=places';

    document.head.appendChild(googleMapsScriptEl);
}
```

I could see the `script` tag with the src has been added to the `<head>` by inspecting in DevTools, but `react-places-autocomplete` still does not work, the page does not load and gave me this error:

```
Error: [react-places-autocomplete]: Google Maps JavaScript API library must be loaded.
```

However if I directly add this line in the `<head>` of `./public/index.html`, the library works:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&libraries=places"></script>
```

Any help?

EDIT: original code has been added (this is basically [the example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete) from `react-places-autocomplete`):

```
import React from 'react';
import PlacesAutocomplete, {
    geocodeByAddress,
    getLatLng,
} from 'react-places-autocomplete';

class LocationSearchInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { address: '', googleMapsAPILoaded: false };
    }

    initGoogleMaps() {
        this.setState({
            googleMapsAPILoaded: true
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.initMap = this.initGoogleMaps;
        var googleMapsScriptEl = document.createElement('script');
        googleMapsScriptEl.type = 'text/javascript';
        googleMapsScriptEl.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey;libraries=places';

        document.head.appendChild(googleMapsScriptEl);
    }

    handleChange = address => {
        this.setState({ address });
    };

    handleSelect = address => {
        geocodeByAddress(address)
            .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
            .then(latLng => console.log('Success', latLng))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <PlacesAutocomplete
                        value={this.state.address}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
                    >
                        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
                            <div>
                                <input
                                    {...getInputProps({
                                        placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                                        className: 'location-search-input',
                                    })}
                                />
                                <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
                                    {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                                    {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                                        const className = suggestion.active
                                            ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                                            : 'suggestion-item';
                                        // inline style for demonstration purpose
                                        const style = suggestion.active
                                            ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                                            : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                                        return (
                                            <div key={this.state.address}
                                                {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                                                    className,
                                                    style,
                                                })}
                                            >
                                                <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </PlacesAutocomplete>
              </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LocationSearchInput;
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have a race-condition where this API script file is being loaded **after** your code needs it. We cannot help you without seeing the source code and analyzing the sequence of events that is unfolding here. You can simply place the script directly in your `index.html` `<head>` tag until you solve it the "react-way"

Comment: @vsync I added some source code. I was suspecting the same thing, but how can I see if the `<script>` has been added after `react-places-autocomplete` needs it?

Comment: Try using [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) instead of injecting the script by yourself, i might have an inert way to prevent race-conditions

Answer (score 0):

You are defining googleMapsScriptEl as a const and after trying to add it a src. 'const' type of variables are not mutable. Try with a let or a var instead.

Comment: Actually, that's wrong. You can still assign properties to an object assigned as `const` the same way you can still add elements to an array. You just can re-assign that variable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add it in the HTML as a script tag.

Answer (score -2):

Original code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&libraries=places"></script>
```

Correction:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&libraries=places" />
```